# How to immediately show a component on a button press?

Tags: react-native

I have a text input that opens up on a button press and the input should become visible and show directly above the keyboard. The issue is the current code works, but the component does not become visible until the user starts typing.

I have tried awaiting the setState call to make sure it's visible but this doesn't solve the problem. It isn't a time thing, it just will not become visible until the user types something. The issue with this is the user can't see what they're typing into.

My component:

```
class MainTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
      inputVisible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this.keyboardDidShow(),
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this.keyboardDidHide(),
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  keyboardDidShow() {
    console.log('keyboard opened');
  }

  keyboardDidHide() {
    console.log('keyboard closed');
    this.setState({ inputVisible: false });
  }

  addTodo() {
    if (this.state.textInput !== '') {
      this.props.addTodo(this.state.textInput);
    }
    this.setState({ textInput: '' });
    return;
  }

  async onFloatingButtonPress() {
    await this.setState({ inputVisible: true });
    this.textInputField.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
        <FlatList
          data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, (item) => {
            return item.date;
          })}
          extraData={this.props.todos}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TodoItem
                todoItem={item}
                deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
        {this.state.inputVisible ?
          <InputAccessoryView>
            <AddTodo
              textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
              addNewTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}
              textInput={this.state.textInput}
              ref={(ref) => { this.textInputField = ref; }}
            />
          </InputAccessoryView>
          :
          <FloatingPlusButton tapToAddEvent={this.onFloatingButtonPress.bind(this)} />
        }
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the keyboard methods are not working either, they both console log when app boots up and never again. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need async and await at your onFloatingButtonPress, usually I only apply async await when it comes to API calling (because it deals with network and you have no idea when the API will return you a result).

However in your case, you want  `this.setState({ inputVisible: true });` to be performed immediately on button press. Try removing the async and await from onFloatingButtonPress()

Comment: If I don't await the set state then the focus call becomes undefined and I get a crash. The focus call can only happen if setState is true. Should I move it somewhere else?

Comment: You can perform setState first, then following with your textInputField.focus(). Meaning, this.textInputFieldFocus will on perform when setState has completed.

this.setState({ 
inputVisible: false 
}, () => { 
this.textInputField.focus(); 
});

Comment: this solution runs but doesn't solve the problem. component is still visible until the user starts typing.

Comment: That's weird. Try adding some background color to see if the view appears but maybe you don't see it? By right, setState will re-render your components again. Meaning your < InputAccessoryView> should be rendered.

Comment: Yea that's the weird part. It has a background color but nothing shows up. Then once I type one character the component appears with the changed background color.